# onNotification is not called when iOS react native app receives a push notif in background

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, background, react-native-push-notification

### Environement

I'm using [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification), and it is configured with:

```js
// top level code in index.js
PushNotification.configure({
  onRegister: function (token) {
    console.log('TOKEN:', token);
  },
  onNotification: onNotif,
  senderID: '11223344556677',
  permissions: {
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  },
  popInitialNotification: false,
  requestPermissions: true,
});
```

Related parts of `yarn list`:

```
├─ react-native@0.60.5
├─ @react-native-community/push-notification-ios@1.0.2
├─ react-native-push-notification@3.1.9
│  └─ @react-native-community/push-notification-ios@^1.0.1
```

APNS certificate is setup correctly. *Background fetch* and *Remote notifications* modes are enabled in *Background Modes* section of *Capabilities* page.

Also, as mentioned in other answers, there is `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

And the message sent to APNS is:

```
{"aps":{"alert": "Test" ,"sound":"default","content-available": 1}}
```

Also tried with silent payload `{"aps":{"content-available": 1}}` and normal payload `{"aps":{"alert": "Test" ,"sound":"default"}}`.

### Problem

Testing on a real device (iPhone 7, running iOS 13), when the app is in foreground, it correctly receives the notification (no actual notif is shown, but `onNotif` is called). But when the app is running in background (and not killed), `onNotif` is not called anymore. I tested with noisy (normal) and silent (with `content-available` and without message) payloads and result is same. Noisy push notifications will appear in notification center, but `onNotif` is not called in either cases.

Comment: Dear Taha, did you find any solution?

Comment: Hello pls have you find the solution ? can you help ?

Comment: I saw somewhere this works on production but not in debug mode